# Checking for the presence of an input field with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

Lets say I have the following form field:

```
<%= simple_form_for @page do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: false, placeholder: "Name" %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

How can I test it's presence?

The following says no matches were found:

`it { should have_field("name")}`

Also tried `"page[name]"`, which is the name given to the field in HTML, but then RSpec gives me this error:

`it { should matcher }`

`RSpec expects the matcher to have a #description method. You should either
add a String to the example this matcher is being used in, or give it a
description method. Then you won't have to suffer this lengthy warning again.`

Is it the square brackets that cause this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Providing that page is a subject:

```
it { should have_selector("form input[name='page[name]']") }
```

Comment: Figured it out, thanks.. I knew this worked but I was looking to use the have_field method.. for some reason an extra squiggly outside of the example was throwing an error with it but not with have_selector... confused the heck out of me. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

What that message is saying is you are missing a description string for the example, which is because you only have `it { should have_field("name")}`

Update your example as follows:

```
it 'has name input field' { should have_field("page[name]")}
```

If you have multiple examples that may fall under same group then you can use `describe` with `it` as:

```
describe 'Page form' do 
  it 'has name input field' { should have_field("page[name]")} 
  it ... { ... }
end
```

Please reference [Better Specs](http://betterspecs.org/) for other suggested best practices in working with RSpec.

Comment: Actually, it's working now without the description string, the example is in a description & has a subject assigned outside of it.. anyways, looks like I had a syntax error, but thanks anyways lol now I know what that error means